# Get all pairs of names where name1's salary< name2's salary

Tags: sql-server

I have this scenario:

[image]

I need roughly something like:

```
foreach(var name in tableNames) 

SELECT Name FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE Salary<(  SELECT Salary FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE Name=name );
```

How to achieve that using SQL?

Comment: Your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58700017/printing-pairs-of-names-where-first-names-selery-seconds-name-salary) was closed for a reason. Don't repost an identical question...

Comment: But now I added my attempt in this one...

Comment: @SeanLange I explained the background but someone edited my post...

Comment: I gotcha. Sadly your professor gave such an unrealistic query it is confusing to people who don't have lots of experience. I can understand your confusion because the desired output here make zero sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a self join:

```
select ee.name name1, e.name name2
from employees e
inner join employees ee on e.salary > ee.salary
order by e.name
```